# Override type declaration when running tsc

Tags: typescript

I have a library I'm attempting to convert over to TypeScript. For now I'm allowing JavaScript, and simply compiling the project with the declaration flag turned on so it can be consumed by other TypeScript projects without errors. Everything else seems to export correctly, except for *one* method which is being typed as `any` for the `comp` arg.

```
export function setup(comp: any[]): void;
```

Is there a way I can override the types for this specific method, either it be through some sort of syntax so I can declare the function arg that `setup` expects without moving the file to a `*.ts` (yet)

My tsconfig.json file looks like the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist",
    "declarationMap": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2019", "dom"],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },

  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.js"]
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused as to what exactly you're trying to achieve, but if I may take a shot in the dark for a solution would be to use generics for your method. Ala. `export<T>(arg: T): void` and when using the export `setup<ArgumentType>(arg)`

Comment: Ah for more context setup is defined in a *.js file. I am trying to figure out how I can override that type when typescript generates the declaration files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [JSDoc type comments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#type) to set the type from a *.js which Typescript will pickup and use.

For example:

```js
// myfile.js

/**
 * @type {(comp: number[]) => void}
 */
export function setup(comp) {
  //...
}
```

Or maybe:

```js
// myfile.js

/**
 * @param {number[]} comp - the array of comp stuff
 */
export function setup(comp) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Second one did the trick, thank you!

Comment: it's a good temporary solution. I'd bite the sour thingy and go .ts...more work right away, but easier in the long run

Comment: That’s the plan